# PostgreSQL - Etcd - Patroni Cluster Restoration Problem

Tags: postgresql, etcd, patroni

I am trying to create PostgreSQL - Etcd - Patroni(PEP) cluster. There are lots of examples on the internet and I have created one and it runs perfect. Yet, this architecture should comply with my company' s backup solution which is NetApp. We are putting the database into backup mode with "SELECT pg_start_backup('test_backup', true);" and then copy all the data files to backup directory.

PEP cluster has a small problem with this solution. Taking backup is running fine, but restoration point is not that much good. In order to restore the leader of the PEP cluster I need stop the database and then move the backup files to the data directory and finally start the restoration. At this point Patroni says the restoration node is a new cluster. Here is the error:

```
    raise PatroniFatalException('Failed to bootstrap cluster')
patroni.exceptions.PatroniFatalException: 'Failed to bootstrap cluster'
2022-04-11 12:49:29,930 INFO: No PostgreSQL configuration items changed, nothing to reload.
2022-04-11 12:49:29,942 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am pgsql_node1
2022-04-11 12:49:29,962 INFO: trying to bootstrap a new cluster
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
```

Also, when I check the patroni cluster status I saw this:

```
root@4cddca032454:/data/backup# patronictl -c /etc/patroni/config.yml list
+ Cluster: pgsql (7085327534197401486) --------+----+-----------+
| Member      | Host       | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| pgsql_node1 | 172.17.0.6 | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
| pgsql_node2 | 172.17.0.7 | Replica | running | 11 |         0 |
| pgsql_node3 | 172.17.0.8 | Replica | running | 11 |         0 |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
```

At this point I have a PEP cluster without a leader. So, how can I solve this issue?

(Note: The restoration node attempted to join right cluster because, before starting the restoration I check cluster status and got this result:

```
root@4cddca032454:/data/backup# patronictl -c /etc/patroni/config.yml list
+ Cluster: pgsql (7085327534197401486) --------+----+-----------+
| Member      | Host       | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| pgsql_node2 | 172.17.0.7 | Replica | running | 11 |         0 |
| pgsql_node3 | 172.17.0.8 | Replica | running | 11 |         0 |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
```

pgsql_node1 is not there.

)

As explained here, "https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/existing_data.html#existing-data" I can create a new cluster after restoration but my priority saving the cluster. Or do I think wrong, all this steps are same with the converting a standalone PostgreSQL database to PEP cluster?

Please let me know if you need any data or something is not clear.

Here is my leader node patroni config file:

```
scope: "cluster"
namespace: "/cluster/"
name: 8d454a228d251

restapi:
  listen: 172.17.0.2:8008
  connect_address: 172.17.0.2:8008

etcd:
  host: 172.17.0.2:2379

  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    check_timeline: true
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      remove_data_directory_on_rewind_failure: true
      remove_data_directory_on_diverged_timelines: true
      use_slots: true

postgresql:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:5433
  connect_address: 172.17.0.2:5432
  use_unix_socket: true
  data_dir: /data/postgresql/
  bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin
  config_dir: /etc/postgresql/14/main
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: "patroni_replication"
      password: "123123"
    superuser:
      username: "patroni_superuser"
      password: "123123"

  parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: '/var/run/postgresql/'
    logging_collector: 'on'
    log_directory: '/var/log/postgresql'
    log_filename: 'postgresql-14-8d454a228d25.log'
    restore_command: 'cp /data/backup/%f %p'
    recovery_target_timeline: 'latest'
    promote_trigger_file: '/tmp/promote'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to restore the primary server (leader) restoring the data directory with a new set of backup files.

After doing the restore in data directory of leader you need to recreate the patroni cluster (remove the keys in DCS) with patronictl remove option.

Example:

stop pgsql_node2
stop pgsql_node3
stop pgsql_node1
on pgsql_node1:
patronictl -c /etc/patroni/config.yml remove <clustername>

start pgsql_node1
start pgsql_node2
start pgsql_node3

Comment: Hi! Yes, you got it correct. There is no other option? Because, in that case the solution will be same with "converting a standalone PostgreSQL database to PEP cluster", right? Instead of recreate I want to recover current instance like using pg_rewind.

Comment: Because my data volume will be at least 3 TB. Recreating the cluster will not be nice.